The car is parked by/on/along?
Which of the following are correct?

The car is parked along the side of the Eleventh Avenue.
The car is parked along the Eleventh Avenue.
The car is parked on the Eleventh Avenue.
The car is parked by the Eleventh Avenue.


Where is the car actually parked? The sample sentences refer to different locations.

Cars parked on a street are usually 'along the side' - parallel to the kerb - unless there are special parking bays. So I would think "on Eleventh Avenue" would be sufficient unless extra information is required.

Streets are normally known as "Eleventh Avenue" without "the", at least in New York and other US cities.

"The car is parked in/on Eleventh Avenue." You only need to say exactly how it is parked if it unusual, for example "The car is parked in the middle of Eleventh Avenue." Otherwise there is no need to explain how a car is parked.
